# Showing a popup after a successful update

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to show a popup box after a successful update. What i did is

In controller

```
var objContext = new KnittingdbContext();

        objContext.ProductTypes.Attach(producttype);
        var obJBlog = objContext.Entry(producttype);

        obJBlog.Property(a => a.ProductTypeCode).IsModified = true;
        obJBlog.Property(a => a.ProductTypeName).IsModified = true;
        objContext.SaveChanges();

        TempData["SuccessEdit"] = "a";

        return RedirectToAction("vwProductTypeIndex");
```

and in vwProductTypeIndex view

```
 @if (TempData["SuccessEdit"] != null)
       {
        <div class="green">
            <p style="color:green;">Updated Successfully</p>
        </div>
       }
```

But the problem is this only shows a text.

I have a message box created using css

```
<!--popup model-->
<div class="modal fade" id="basic" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basic" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog  modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:#ffffff; borderolid 4px #44d775;margin-top:253px; left:-25px;">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#44d775; height:15px;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top:-12px;">x</button>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style=" color:yellow; font-size:large; top:-10px; left:115px;" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="text-align:center;"></h4>
            </div>
            <p style="text-align:center; font-family:'Ebrima'; color:black; margin-top:15px;"> <strong> saved Successfully </strong></p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--/end popup model--
```

I want this popup box to appear instead of that text. How can i achieve this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: So are you aware about Jquery dialog box and don't know how to implement in this particular case?

Comment: @ssilas777, Thanks for replying! :) My friend provided me with this popup box. But i have no idea of how to implement it with my project. Pls help.

Answer (score 2):

try to your div tag and pass the id

```
    <div class="green"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basic">
        <p style="color:green;">Updated Successfully</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: This fires the text again and when clicking on that text modal gets fired. I want to get the modal appeared directly without having to click on the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Bootstrap modal* here like this

```
@if(TempData["SuccessEdit"] !=null)
{
   <div  class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Change Password</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">                       
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: you have to add bootstrap js and bootstrap css in your page.

Comment: not working. i added the bootsrap.js and bootstrap.css also. And then bootstrap.min.js as well. But couldn't get it worked. Do i have to use ajax begin form instead of html begin form to achieve this. Beacause i think calling the id of this model is a must to get it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First add your modal in end of your body tag, or wherever you want, like this:

```
<body>
    <!-- your other codes -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="basic" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basic" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog  modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:#ffffff; borderolid 4px #44d775;margin-top:253px; left:-25px;">
                <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#44d775; height:15px;">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top:-12px;">x</button>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style=" color:yellow; font-size:large; top:-10px; left:115px;" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="text-align:center;"></h4>
                </div>
                <p style="text-align:center; font-family:'Ebrima'; color:black; margin-top:15px;"> <strong> saved Successfully </strong></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And in scripts section add following code:

```
@section Scripts {
    @if((bool?)TempData["SuccessEdit"] ==true)
    {
         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#basic').modal('show');
            });
        </script>
    }
}
```

Now you could add following line in your action method:

```
TempData["SuccessEdit"] = true;
```

You must also add jQuery and bootstrap.js in your view as well.